# Matrix power help/Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to raise a matrix to a next matrix and subtrat one before taking the product.

e.g.

```
A = [2 3 5       
     2 3 0]

B = [2 2 1
     1 2 0]
```

so `prod(A.^B-1)` would be:

first row `(2^2-1)*(3^2-1)*(5^1-1)=96`

second row `(2^1-1)*(3^2-1)=8`

and we would have `prod(A.^B-1) = 96, 81`. the trick also to skip past the zero, i keep getting zero or NaN, i think the zero is being calculated as well.

Is there a way to code this,

this is the code I have in mind

```
if A~=0 && B~=0
    prod(A.^B-1)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) to replace instances where `A.^B-1` is `0`:

```
A = [2 3 5;2 3 0];
B = [2 2 1;1 2 0];
C = A.^B-1;
C(C==0) = 1;  % Replace zeros with ones
D = prod(C,2) % Product across the columns
```

which returns

```
D =

    96
     8
```

provided that you remove the zeros, I don't think that you should get `NaN` unless your original matrices contain it. However, You can replace it in the same manner as well (`C(isnan(C)) = 1;`).